# jQuery hover is not working when I use display:none property of my input

Tags: jquery

I am working on editing profile picture and I am using jQuery for it. jQuery hover function is completely working when I am not using `disply:none` property on my input. But when I am using `display:none`, it's not working on hover. My code is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#img1").click(function() {
            $("#file1").click();
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#img1").hide();
        $("#photoframe").hover(function() {
            $("#img1").show();
        }, function() {
            $("#img1").hide();
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="photoframe">
    <form name='frm1' id="frm1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
        <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" style="display:none" />
    </form>
    <img src="img/edit_button.png" id="img1" name="img1" alt="">
    <div id="showimage" name='showimage'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _Sidenote:_ You don't need two `ready`, the code can be merged

Comment: Have you thought of a solution in `css`? It's much much better then JavaScript solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just include below code instead of style="display:none"

```
<input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" style="visibility:hidden" />
```

Answer (score 0):

When the DOM is loaded, its supposed contents are not visible, so, the `#photoframe` appears as though its empty. To change this, we need to assign it with width, and height values. Below is a code snippet to illustrate this finding.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#img1").click(function() {
    $("#file1").click();
  });

  $("#img1").hide();

  $("#photoframe").hover(function() {
    $("#img1").show();
  }, function() {
    $("#img1").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
#photoframe {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #3ef;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="photoframe">
  <form name='frm1' id="frm1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
    <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" style="display:none" />
  </form>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/FKb02wL.jpg" id="img1" name="img1" alt="">
  <div id="showimage" name='showimage'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did the donkey make a hill of dirt to escape the pit and then kicked the farmer in the head?

Comment: @zer00ne I hope it did.